# XML-serialization Array of Class

Tags: c#, xml, arrays, serialization

i've two classes A and B. A is for the ROOT-Element and B should be an array of B.

```
public class A
{
    public B[] b;
}

public class B
{
    public string param1;
    public string param2;
}
```

Create instances and fill with data look like this:

```
A test = new A();
test.b = new B[2];

test.b[0] = new B();
test.b[1] = new B();

test.b[0].param1 = "b0-p1";
test.b[0].param2 = "b0-p2";
test.b[1].param1 = "b1-p1";
test.b[1].param2 = "b1-p2";
```

Now serialize:

```
System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer ser = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(A));
System.IO.TextWriter wr = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"c:\ser.xml");
ser.Serialize(wr, test);
wr.Close();
```

The generated XML look like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<A xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org /2001/XMLSchema">
  <b>
    <B>
      <param1>b0-p1</param1>
      <param2>b0-p2</param2>
    </B>
    <B>
      <param1>b1-p1</param1>
      <param2>b1-p2</param2>
    </B>
  </b>
</A>
```

But I want to have this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<A xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org /2001/XMLSchema">
  <b>
    <param1>b0-p1</param1>
    <param2>b0-p2</param2>
  </b>
  <b>
    <param1>b1-p1</param1>
    <param2>b1-p2</param2>
  </b>
</A>
```

Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong?

regards raiserle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Decorate `B[] b` property with `XmlElementAttribute`:

```
public class A
{
    [XmlElement("b")]
    public B[] b;
}
```

You'll need `using System.Xml.Serialization;` at the top of the file to make it work.

Comment: Thx,

i've tested it with wrong attribute: `System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArray("b")` and
`System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayItem("b")`

Thx, thx .. thx